# Azure ARM nested template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I keep getting the error `Deployment template parse failed: 'Required property 'type' not found in JSON. Path 'parameters.environment' ...` when deploying an ARM template referencing additional nested templates.

All are ok if deployed separately. The issue only started after adding the 4th nested template reference. Any ARM nested template deployment limit I should know of?

Answer (score 0):

no, this is not an arm template limit. you forgot to specify parameter type for parameter named environment in your template.